# Using HTTP POST/SOAP Web Service in Ionic

Tags: http, ionic-framework

I'm new to phone app development and I am using `Ionic`. The site I want to scrape has a web service to get the information. It provides both `SOAP` and `HTTP` Get/POST code.

First, I'm not sure whether it's okay to use the HTTP POST call in my code. Second, I'm not sure how to add it - where? - to my Ionic code.

I've done this with puppeteer only to find they have the information available through a web service. I've read several of the posts here but they assume I already know how to use this.

```
POST /webservices/wsadoption.asmx/AdoptableSearch HTTP/1.1
Host: wspetangoprd2.azurewebsites.net
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

authkey=string&speciesID=string&sex=string&ageGroup=string&location=string&site=string&onHold=string&orderBy=string&primaryBreed=string&secondaryBreed=string&specialNeeds=string&noDogs=string&noCats=string&noKids=string&stageID=string
```

Also I see this in their page for a form:

```
<form target="_blank" action='http://ws.petango.com/webservices/wsadoption.asmx/AdoptableSearch' method="POST">
```

...obviously this is part of a form.

I would like to know how I connect to this webservice in `Ionic`. Is it enough to use the action in the form code? Do I need to npm anything?